# Is there a relationship between the L2-norm and the Pearson chi-square test?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, matrix

Suppose I have two datasets, $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, with some data weighting term (or error term), $\mathbf{e}$. I can compute the L2-norm for these two sets by the following:

$$(\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b})^\mathbf{T}\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{e})^{-1}(\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b})$$

where $\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{e})^{-1}$ is a square matrix with the inverse of the error terms along the diagonals.

I've noticed that this is very similar to the chi-square statistic

$$\chi^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{(a_k - b_k)^2}{m_k}$$

where $\mathbf{m}$ are the "expected numbers".

If there is a difference between $\mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{m}$?

Are the L2-norm and the chi-square statistic the same thing assuming they are both normalized by some similar vector (e.g. $\mathbf{e}=\mathbf{m}$)?